# Swift JSON POST Login API call getting invalid credential error

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to Implement Login `API` `POST` call in my application. Here, my issues I am sending my valid username, password etc, to my server but I am getting Invalid `credential` error.

If I test in `Postman` everything working fine but same API and parameters not working by using below code. I am getting Invalid credential error. how to fix this?

Please help me to `simplified` the lines of code also proper `POST` call method.

> NOTE: I am not looking third party library (almofire, etc)

Below my POST method code

```
let parameters = ["employeeid" : empid, "password" : passowrd, "platform" : platform]
            let url = URL(string: Base_url().domain_URL + Login_url().signin_URL)!
            let session = URLSession.shared
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            do {
                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

                guard error == nil else { return }
                guard let data = data else { return }

                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                        print(json)

                        let status_code : Int = json["statusCode"]! as! Int
                        print(status_code)

                        switch status_code {
                        case 200 :
                            let message : String = json["message"]! as! String
                            print(message)
                            break
                        case 422 :
                            break
                        default:
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.Alert(Meesage: "Error: Server Error! Please try after some time.")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
```

Comment: It should be something related to the API implementation. The above code is not helpful to find the issue. Can you add more information like how you are calling that api from postman, what are the fields required, are you using same api end-point and parameter names in both ios and postman etc ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I am using same API in post man and inside application. Postman giving me result but above code showing invalid credential. I think the username and password not sending properly. how to debug it?

Comment: As per the above code, you are not appending the empid and password to the request

Comment: @DecDev once check parameters key,values

Comment: You should debug it on a server

Comment: @Lu_ if server side problem mean I don't get output right. its giving response but As per Naveen Kommuri commends I think I am not appending params properly. please post some sample fr reference.

Comment: @NaveenKommuri Yes I think so. Can you please provide some sample

Comment: if you check it on server you will know exactly what is wrong, you can check step by step what params are wrong

Comment: @Lu_ Sure I will check it. Btw above posted code proper way or anything I want to change it? I would like to simplified above code, why we need to use this much lines

Answer (score 0):

```
let parameters = ["id":"0","userName":self.usernameTextField.text!,"email":self.emailTextField.text!,"password":self.passwordTextField.text!]
print(parameters)
```

Comment: I tested its printing correctly. Nothing wrong in params value